# sample active directory ldif file with apacheds

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap, ldif

Here there is a spring-security example, [ldap-xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/ldap-xml), which runs a ldap server and imports a LDIF file for testing:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/ldap-xml/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml

```
[...]
    <s:ldap-server ldif="classpath:users.ldif" port="33389"/>

    <s:authentication-manager>
        <s:ldap-authentication-provider
            group-search-filter="member={0}"
            group-search-base="ou=groups"
            user-search-base="ou=people"
            user-search-filter="uid={0}"
        />
        <s:authentication-provider ref='secondLdapProvider' />
    </s:authentication-manager>
[...]
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/ldap-xml/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/users.ldif

```
[...]
dn: uid=rod,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Rod Johnson
sn: Johnson
uid: rod
userPassword: koala
[...]
```

---

I need to modify this working example, in where the user-search-criteria is based on sAMAccountName instead of uid. I modify the users.ldif as follows:

```
[...]
dn: cn=rod,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Rod Johnson
sn: Johnson
sAMAccountName: rod
userPassword: koala
[...]
```

but apacheds shows a warning when importing users.ldif:

```
OID for name 'samaccountname' was not found within the OID registry
```

It seems that I need to add this new attribute, sAMAccountName, by modifing the LDAP schema. how to do that in the ldap-xml example?

In this [gist example](https://gist.github.com/jakeballard/9124822) they modify the schema using "changetype: add". however adding this in users.ldif results in an error `We cannot have entries when reading a file which already contains changes`. In the gist example, they mention to update the schema running the `ldifde`command. How should I modify the [ldap-xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/ldap-xml) project to do this?

How I need to modify the [ldap-xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/ldap-xml) project, so that my users.ldif can contain a sAMAccountName attribute?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question (which, strictly speaking, isn't Spring Security related) - you're looking to understand how to get a custom LDAP schema element (sAMAccountName) configured in ApacheDS server, correct?

Comment: correct. how to do that inside the spring-security framework. spring-security can easily embed a ldap server and import a ldif file with the s:ldap-server tag. how can i get a custom ldap schema element inside the spring-security framework.

Comment: @DavidPortabella Did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following (it's the minimal fragment of Microsoft's schema that contains sAMAccountName) at the beginning of users.ldif file:

```
dn: cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: metaSchema
objectclass: top
cn: microsoft

dn: ou=attributetypes, cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: attributetypes

dn: m-oid=1.2.840.113556.1.4.221, ou=attributetypes, cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: metaAttributeType
objectclass: metaTop
objectclass: top
m-oid: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
m-name: sAMAccountName
m-equality: caseIgnoreMatch
m-syntax: 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
m-singleValue: TRUE

dn: ou=objectclasses, cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: objectClasses

dn: m-oid=1.2.840.113556.1.5.6, ou=objectclasses, cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: metaObjectClass
objectclass: metaTop
objectclass: top
m-oid: 1.2.840.113556.1.5.6
m-name: securityPrincipal
m-supObjectClass: top
m-typeObjectClass: AUXILIARY
m-must: sAMAccountName

[rest of users.ldif]
```

Now add new objectClass to person entries:

```
[...]
dn: cn=rod,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: securityPrincipal   <--- new objectClass
cn: Rod Johnson
sn: Johnson
sAMAccountName: rod
userPassword: koala
[...]
```

It's not enough to have new entries. ApacheDS' configuration in Spring Security has [disabled schema interceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/server/ApacheDSContainer.java#L109), so new schema entries are not created by default. We can turn it on by creating BeanPostProcessor that fixes this:

```java
package com.example.test.spring;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.directory.server.core.interceptor.Interceptor;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.server.ApacheDSContainer;

import static org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.isEmpty;

public class ApacheDSContainerConfigurer implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private List<Interceptor> interceptors;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof ApacheDSContainer){
            ApacheDSContainer dsContainer = ((ApacheDSContainer) bean);
            setInterceptorsIfPresent(dsContainer);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    private void setInterceptorsIfPresent(ApacheDSContainer container) {
        if (!isEmpty(interceptors)) {
            container.getService().setInterceptors(interceptors);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    public void setInterceptors(List<Interceptor> interceptors) {
        this.interceptors = interceptors;
    }

}
```

We have to register and configure bean in application context:

```
<bean class="com.example.test.spring.ApacheDSContainerConfigurer">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.normalization.NormalizationInterceptor"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.authn.AuthenticationInterceptor"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.referral.ReferralInterceptor"/>
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.authz.AciAuthorizationInterceptor"/>-->
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.authz.DefaultAuthorizationInterceptor"/>-->
            <bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.exception.ExceptionInterceptor"/>
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.changelog.ChangeLogInterceptor"/>-->
            <bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.operational.OperationalAttributeInterceptor"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.schema.SchemaInterceptor"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.subtree.SubentryInterceptor"/>
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.collective.CollectiveAttributeInterceptor"/>-->
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.event.EventInterceptor"/>-->
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.trigger.TriggerInterceptor"/>-->
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.directory.server.core.journal.JournalInterceptor"/>-->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It should be working now.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and tried the solution given by @Karol, but it didn't work for me.
I was using the `LdapTemplate` provided by Spring Framework for accessing the Ldap Server.

The problem was that the **embedded ldap server** (it was **ApacheDS** in my case) doesn't support certain **attributes** like `sAMAccountName`. As a solution for testing, I made these attribute names in my code configurable from **properties file** and replaced the attribute names to the names available in ApacheDS embedded server in test environment's properties file. And it worked like a charm.

For example, in actual environment the search by LdapTemplate is based on `sAMAccountName` attribute, but in test environment the search happens with `uid` attribute.

Comment: It's strange it didn't work. It was ApacheDS in my case as well and the solution I provided is just registering sAMAccountName attribute in the schema. Maybe you accidentally missed some step. Your alternative also looks good.